# Subtracting Scalar value from vector matrix

Tags: vectors

Is this possible

$3-[3,4,5,7]$

I want to subtract a scalar value from $n\times 1$ vector.

Comment: if you mean subtracting 3 from all entries sure you can [3,4,5,7]-[3,3,3,3].  Here the latter is also a vector. But subtracting a vector from a scalar has no meaning.

Comment: Some softwares, e.g. octave, would interpret it as $[3,3,3,3]-[3,4,5,7]$, but this notation would be non-standard in theoretical mathematics.

Comment: Yes I knew the Matrix subtraction theory but as in Octave It has been done, I was wondering How could it be possible?So It means  scalar value should be converted to Scalar matrix of same dimension?

Comment: How could it be possible?  The software parsing the things you enter tries hard to make sense out of them. If you give it `5*[1,2]` you get `[5,10]`, consistent with mathematical notation. But software is more flexible and also allows + - instead of * there, with similar effect.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato I didn't get you.I am saying simply 3-[1,2,5,6,7] is not possible where 'not possible ' means For matrix and vector subtraction , there is should be equal number of dimensions in matrix involved otherwise It  is not theoretically right.However in above comment I see someone convert 3 into scalar matrix but it is not mentioned anywhere in Calculas or Linear algebra books.

Comment: Watch me doing this: $3-[3,4,5,7] = [0,-1,-2,-4]$. I did it! So it's not impossible.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato well done now could you please share a link where I can see some example for matrix addition ir subtraction with scalar value.Do not send me Octave/matlab link

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3-%5B3%2C4%2C5%2C7%5D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the interpretation of "$[a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4]$". For example, one can think of this as a function $n\mapsto a_n$ with the domain $\{1,2,3,4\}$. (This is often done with infinite sequences). Thinking of your vector as a function
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases} 
3,\quad &\text{if } n=1\\
4,\quad &\text{if } n=2\\
5,\quad &\text{if } n=3\\
7,\quad &\text{if } n=4 
\end{cases}
$$
you will find nothing unusual in the operation $3-f$. We do things like $g = af+b$ with functions all the time.

Naturally, $g=3-f$ is the function such that 
$$
g(n) = \begin{cases} 
0,\quad &\text{if } n=1\\
-1,\quad &\text{if } n=2\\
-2,\quad &\text{if } n=3\\
-4,\quad &\text{if } n=4 
\end{cases}
$$
which could be more concisely encoded as $[0,-1,-2,-4]$.

---

Some software products follow the approach described above: e.g., 
[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3-%5B3%2C4%2C5%2C7%5D) or Matlab.

Comment: Great I got this point now that I ve to convert my normal vector into normal sequences.How will you describe if it is mxn matrix?

Comment: Same thing: a real matrix can be considered as a function from the set of pairs $(i,j)$ into reals.

Answer (score 2):

In a vector space, you add vectors to vectors, and multiply scalars times vectors, but normally adding scalars to vectors is not defined.